# Why are the |o-e| values for 2x2 chi squared independence tests always equal?

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence

When performing chi-squared independence tests, why do 2x2 tests always have every residual value (o-e) equal?
Why is this not true for tests with unequal amounts of rows and columns?

Comment: The premise underlying your second question doesn't hold -- you can have equal number of rows and columns but not have equal magnitude of residuals  in every cell (consider a 3x3 table, which has equal number of rows and columns but doesn't have $|o_{ij}-e_{ij}|$ constant). It's 2x2 vs anything else, not 2x2 vs "unequal number of rows and columns"

Answer (score 2):

It's due to the fact that the row and column sums of the expected values are equal to the row and column sums of the observed values. (If you fix the row and column total then the sum of observed values in each row and column is fixed, and the expected values in that row or column have the same sum.)

So whatever difference one observed has from its expected, the others differences in the same row or column have to add to the negative of it.

In a 2x2 table there is only one other value to account for the whole of that negative difference, so its $o-e$ residual must be the negative of its counterpart. This in turn forces the diagonally opposite cell (of the one you first considered) to have the same residual, leaving all four the same in absolute value.

Algebraically: let the column sums be $n_{\cdot 1}$ and $n_{\cdot 2}$ respectively, and the row sums in turn be $n_{1\cdot}$ and $n_{2\cdot}$. So we have in the first row that $o_{11}+o_{12} = n_{1\cdot}=e_{11}+e_{12}$ and so on, and similarly for the other row and both columns.

Consider the residuals ($o-e$) in the first column, first row -- whatever the value of $o_{11}-e_{11}$, we have that the other value in the same row must be its opposite: $o_{12}-e_{12} =  (n_{1\cdot}-o_{11}) -(n_{1\cdot}-e_{11}) = -o_{11} - (-e_{11})=-(o_{11} - e_{11})$. The same applies to the second value in the first column. We can use the same argument to establish that  $o_{22}-e_{22} = o_{11} - e_{11}$ (since it will be the negative of the value above it, which in turn will be the negative of the value to its left, so the diagonally opposite ones must then have the same sign (as well as being the same in magnitude).

Larger tables don't have that restriction in both directions at the same time so you won't necessarily have that (say) $o_{22}-e_{22} = o_{11} - e_{11}$.